# how to remove comma from a file using linux

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I have a huge file from which I need to remove commas

file

```
ae,1,nnn,00000,      ,type,    ,0000
ae,1,mmm,00000,      ,type,    ,1111
```

output I need

```
ae1nnn0000      type      0000
ae1mmm0000      type      1111
```

can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: `tr -d , < input > output`

Comment: if I use this the file is not getting sorted 
sort file.dat | tr -d , < file.dat

Comment: You really need to learn to ask proper questions. You can't just use part of your problem/task in your question text and then keep asking for other parts later on in the comments.  [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 options:

- tr: `tr -d, <input >output`
- grep: `grep -o '[^,]*' <input >output`
- sed: `sed 's/,//g' <input >output`

Comment: if I use this the file is not getting sorted sort file.dat | tr -d , < file.dat

Comment: @nischithashekar your question doesn't mention anything about sorting. But you cannot provide 2 inputs to `tr` at the same time (1 input via the pipe, the second input via IO redirect)